# Evolution and Office 365

Tags: evolution

In Evolution Mail there is an option to create an account for Exchange with an OWA address. Does someone have an idea how to get the required data from Office 365 to get working in Evolution?
Microsoft support did not help and refused my help request because of the word Ubuntu in the post ;)

The OWA url is https://amsprd0302.outlook.com/owa but I do not know what username and mailbox name to use.

Comment: I have this same issue. I enter my username and password. I've tried both Secure and Plaintext Password. Still, I only get an error message: "Could not configure Exchange account because 
an unknown error occurred. Check the URL, 
username and password, and try again." I'm certain I have the correct URL, username, and password, because I've logged into the site just fine.

Answer (score 5):

It is very rough at this point, but the [evolution-ews](https://live.gnome.org/Evolution/EWS) plugin partially works with MS 365. It should be available in the same repo you use to get evolution-mapi. This isn't a 100% solution, but it (for me) is better than the DavMail solution or using WINE/VM/Firefox.

Comment: I will have to give that a try. Neither can't confirm nor can't negate that it works or not.

Comment: Since I upgraded to 18.04, I can say that Evolution works perfectly with Office 365. Use `https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx` as your Host URL, your complete email address as the username, and for Authentication, only _Basic_ worked for me, but Email, Contacts, and Calendar all work and sync as well as an Outlook client.

Answer (score 4):

Edit your account.  (edit>preferences>select your account>edit)

Go to "Recieving Email"

Your username is your full email address, e.g. myname@something.com

Your host URL is https://outlook.office365.com

Once you've entered those 2 bits, click "Fetch URL".  It will prompt you for your password, then populate the required fields for connectivity.

Done.

Comment: But it doesn't. It says Autodiscovery query failed: 401 Unauthorized. It doesn't prompt me for my password either. Basically it's broken.

Answer (score 2):

If you use https://m.outlook.com and click the "Fetch URL" button the rest of the fields should auto populate. This is working on evolution 3.8.x

Comment: This is also using the evolution-ews plugin 3.8.x

Comment: That gives the same error: Autodiscovery query failed: 401 Unauthorized. It doesn't prompt me for my password either. Basically it's broken.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research. It appears as if Evolution only supports Exchange 2000 and Exchange 2003 via OWA. To use Evolution with Exchange 2007, one must use the MAPI protocol, which I don't believe is available on Office 365.

Comment: I can't confirm that completely because I can't test this properly. But it seems to be the only acceptable answer. Thanks for your research.

Answer (score 1):

For outlook.com I could connect Evolution 3.20.5 with these settings:

**Host URL:** `https://outlook.live.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx`

**OAB URL:** `https://outlook.live.com/OAB`

No "Fetch URL" was needed.

Answer (score 0):

i think the username and password are

username = your email address eg me@something.com

and password is your email password

usually if you are using office365 it will be the same creditials you use to log in

i think..

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is https://amsprd0302.outlook.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx. Beware, service is spotty. Hopefully this package will be updated to support Office 365 better.

Comment: I could give that a try if my friend still has Office 365. He realized that the whole M$ thing is "little bit" proprietary and not well supported on Linux.

Comment: It works with https://m.outlook.com/ews/Services.wsdl

Comment: Nope, they all fail the same way: Autodiscovery query failed: 401 Unauthorized. It doesn't prompt me for my password either. Basically it's broken.

Comment: It's now 2016 and Evolution still doesn't support Orifice365.

Answer (score 0):

Try in Thunderbird and copy over the details. Thunderbird auto-finds the login details so if it gets it right you can just copy to Evolution.

Comment: Can't say anymore. No more OWA. I'm happy with that ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got things working on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.2 using `https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx` as the host url and fetching with my email and password.

Source:
https://kb.wisc.edu/office365/page.php?id=28462

Answer (score 0):

I had a working connection before office365, when the company changed to office365 I had this issue. My connection worked with https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx. But most important, before the change I only had to provide the username, so by playing with changing stuff I tried providing username@host.xxx in the Username field and it all started working.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

this article helped me basically you open up gnome settings (after installing evolution) click on exchange and input your login and then click custom. in coustom enter your email again next to username and put "outlook.office365.com" next to server. if done correctly gnome and evolution will handle the rest but open up eveloution to chenk it has regesterd there. afer that it is done and your calander should sink up with gnome!

https://kamarada.github.io/en/2017/09/06/use-evolution-to-connect-to-office-365-on-linux/#.XMTV2h-YXza